# Why is the result changing every time I run my TensorFlow model in my code?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

such a problem I wrote this code, but I can’t understand when I run the code every time, the result changes, then: (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (1,1,1) and so on, can you tell me please what the problem is? even on the data on which the model was trained, the result is still not what is expected. Thanks

```
// Input data (genre, duration, lead actor)
const data = [
  [1, 1, 1],    // like it
  [0, 0, 1],    // doesn't like it
  [1, 0, 0],    // doesn't like it
  [0, 1, 0],    // doesn't like it
  [0, 1, 1],    // doesn't like it
  [1, 0, 1],    // doesn't like it
  [1, 1, 0],    // doesn't like it
];

// Tags (0 - Dislike, 1 - Like)
const labels = [
  1,    // like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
  0,    // doesn't like it
];

const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [3], units: 4, activation: 'relu' }));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid', }));

model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

const inputData = tf.tensor2d(data, [data.length, 3]);
const labelData = tf.tensor1d(labels);


model.fit(inputData, labelData, { epochs: 200 })
  .then(() => {
    // test model
    const testData = [
      [1, 1, 1],    // like it
      [0, 1, 0],    // Don't like it
      [0, 0, 1]     // Don't like it
    ];

    const predictions = model.predict(tf.tensor2d(testData));
    const predictedLabels = predictions.round().dataSync();

    console.log('result:', predictedLabels);
  });
```

result must be 1, 0, 0

Comment: Have u tried this [`tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed)?

Comment: thank you, but i can't add it tenserflow.js, i get error that this function doesn't exist, can you help how can i implement this in tensorflow.js ?

Comment: Go to the link above again, notice that it is equivalent to 3 line of code, random, numpy, and tf.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written appears to be fine and should work as expected. However, one possible reason for the inconsistent results is the relatively small size of the training data and the randomness inherent in the initialization of the model's weights.

Every time you run the program, the model's initial weights are randomly assigned. Due to the stochastic nature of these models, the initial weights can greatly affect the model's ability to learn, especially when the amount of data is small.

Lastly, increase the number of epochs for training might also help the model learn better, but it could also lead to overfitting, especially with small datasets. But during this test I feel like you need overfitting also. But if your model is well learned, don't think about consistency.

But if you really need consistencym the seed parameter will give you consistency but you cannot use with Tf.js. But in TensorFlow Python you can set a seed for the random number generator, and then you save and convert that model to use in TensorFlow.js, the weights that the model learned during training will be preserved. That means the initial random seed in Python effectively influences the final model that you use in JavaScript.

You can define your model like this:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, 
                                activation='sigmoid', 
                                kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=0), 
                                bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()))
```

Comment: how i understood, better write machine learning by Python, because tensorflow js hasn't all options like tensorflow on python ? i just have never worked with AI, and got about tensorflow.js, and JS is mine language into job. Can you suggest please maybe smth from which part better start ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it, i added just more repeated data in train, example i have: [1, 1, 1] and others similar array with 3 inputs that repeats ~ 10 times, and finally i get the result that i expect